# Unable to write to nfs on centos6

Tags: centos6, nfs, mount

I have 2 webservers and 3 backend servers. I made one of the directory(from webserver 2) as NFS. I successfully mounted the directory '/mnt/products/files' and had it visible from all the servers(including 3 backend servers) under /projects/www/share on all the servers, except the server which mounted the directory.

I created 'webadmin' user and 'webadmingroup' on all the servers. 'webadmin' user belongs to 'webadmingroup'.

I changed the ownership of '/mnt/products/files' as 'webadmin' and 'webadmingroup' and changed the permission with 755.

The problem is that I am unable to write to the NFS directory from client servers with 'webadmin' user. I am unable to write to it with 'root' user, but if possible, i don't want to use 'root'.

What should I do to be able to write NFS directory '/projects/www/share' from all the servers?  Even though I am using the same user, I can't.

Is there anything that I need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFS write access is a bit tricky at the first time :-)

1: Please check if your user and group webadmin has the same user ID and group ID as on the webservers. NFS access is based on the IDs. In a multi-user setting the first thing most admins do is somehow synchronize user ids to user names and group ids to group names over the machines. E.g. with NIS, LDAP or automated /etc/group and /etc/passwd.  (Command:   id webadmin)

2: The entry on /etc/exports on the NFS server must be rw (not ro)

Good thing: NFS is still the same on Linux distributions (and UNIX types, too). 
I've found following resources best to understand the config:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/storage_administration_guide/nfs-serverconfig

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

If you still encounter problems, it might be a good idea to post your /etc/exports (of the NFS server) and your /etc/fstab (of the NFS client).

Comment: thanks for the response..   

Here is the /etc/exports in the server.
/mnt/products/files           xx.xx.xx.xxx(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)


This is fstab. 
xx.xx.xx.xxx://mnt/products/files   /projects/www/share   nfs      auto,noatime,nolock,bg,nfsvers=3,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0


I checked the uid and gid. uid and gid in webadmin in the server 500, but it's in 501 in the client server. 
I changed only the uid to match with the one from the serer. Do i need to change the gid as well?

Comment: I certainly would recommend also to sync the gid! (Even if it works now without, it will bite you in the least convenient time).